# How to extend absolutely positioned child divs beyond centred parent div with overflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've read and tried a lot of `"how to extend child div beyond parent div"` posts (a few hours worth), and been live testing in Firebug as well but I can't figure out how to extend child divs beyond a parent div where there are several positioning and overflow constraints.

**Goals** (in reference to code snippet below)

- Make the first `valid alert` display beyond `form_container`.
- Scroll `valid alert` when scrolling ie don't make it 'fixed'.

**Constraints**

- `form_container` must be centred.
- `form_container` must have `overflow-y: auto`.

The actual implementation is complex, so I've simplified the structure below:

```
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<div id="form_container">
    <form id="my_form">
    <div class="message_container">
        <div class="valid_alert">valid alert</div>
    </div>
    <p>filler</p>
    <p>filler</p>
    <div class="message_container">
        <div class="valid_alert">valid alert</div>
    </div>
    <p>filler</p>
    <p>filler</p>
    <p>filler</p>
    </form>
</div>
```

**What I've Tried**

As mentioned, I've tried many approaches such as wrapping the parent div and applying different `overflow` and `position` properties at various levels, but to lessen the complexity of this post, the barebones [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/LZxNm/) is probably more useful and consists of the above HTML and the CSS below:

```
#form_container {
    background:salmon;
    height:100px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    margin:auto;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

.message_container {
    position:absolute;
}

.valid_alert {
    position:absolute;
    background:limegreen;
    top:-25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/LZxNm/

I'm open to any suggestions which satisfy the goals and constraints, for example either refactoring the HTML structure or even using Javascript/jQuery wizardry.

**Edit:**

For reference, adding some of the mechanisms of jQuery's [offset()](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) as discovered through the Firebug console which, just as an idea, could possibly be used in a solution:

```
var myDiv = $("#my_div"); // create jQuery object

myDiv.offset(); // find the current offset

Object { top=119, left=510.51666259765625}

var currentOffset = myDiv.offset(); // assign the current offset to a jQuery variable

currentOffset; // view the value of the jQuery variable

Object { top=119, left=510.51666259765625}

new_top = currentOffset['top'] + 10; // create a new value of the top offset

129

new_left = currentOffset['left'] + 10; // create a new value of the left offset

520.5166625976562

myDiv.offset({top:new_top, left:new_left}); // set the new values as the offset

myDiv.offset; // view the new offset values

Object { top=129, left=520.5166625976562}
```

Comment: If the parent has the style `overflow` property set to something other than `visible`, it *will* be clipped, unless its `position` property is set to `fixed`. So you have to rely on a little Javascript to make things work... or *a lot* of it if the page is more complicated. I wouldn't recommend this route, though.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I assume you mean setting the child div to be fixed (as setting the parent to fixed doesn't change anything), in which case yes it escapes the parent div, but then it is fixed upon scrolling.  Could you provide any further info on the Javascript approach?  I looked into `offset()` but it seems to position things relative to the document.  Are there any other terms I should be looking up?

Comment: The hint would be listening to the parent's `scroll` event, and move the `fixed` descendant accordingly in order to mimic a scrollable element. At this point, you can even put `.valid_alert` elements *outside* `#form_container`, and giving it a more manageable absolute positioning. If that's ok with your requirements, there's a foreseeable solution.